# Accessing JSON data with Swift

Tags: json, swift, json-serialization

I have an array of JSON data from the following call:

```
guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [Any] else {
print("Not containing JSON")
return
}
```

when I run print(json) I get the following in the output:

```
[{
"CREATED_BY" = "DOMAIN\\USER";
"CREATED_DATE" = "2016-11-28T08:43:59";
STATUS = U;
"WIDGET_NUMBER" = K11;
"UPDATED_BY" = "<null>";
"UPDATED_DATE" = "<null>";
}, {
"CREATED_BY" = "DOMAIN\\USER";
"CREATED_DATE" = "2016-05-09T08:46:23";
STATUS = U;
"WIDGET_NUMBER" = 89704;
"UPDATED_BY" = "<null>";
"UPDATED_DATE" = "<null>";
}]
```

I am trying to get all of the WIDGETNUMBER values in the array of JSON data.  The json variable is a Any type and I have not been able to convert to a struct so far.  Is there an easy way to get the elements from the JSON objects?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an array of dictionaries

```
for item in json {
    if let item = item as? [String: Any],  let widgetNo = item["WIDGET_NUMBER"] {
        print(widgetNo)
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this I got the error `Cast from '(String, JSON)' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails`

Comment: @Telarian JSON is not a built in type so I suppose you are using some 3rd party library. Probably you don't need to cast and should work with the JSON type directly but I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your content is array of Dictionary, so that you must convert each element Dictionary to Json

```
for dic in content {
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)
        print(jsonData)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Or you can read value of **WIDGET_NUMBER** direct from Dictionary

```
for dic in content {
    print(dic["WIDGET_NUMBER"] ?? "Not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joakim's answer is spot on for getting the widget number. For your struct, be sure to add something like this as an initializer to map your object.

```
let widgetNumber: Int
let user: String

    init?(json:[String:Any]) {

      guard let widgetNumber = json["WIDGET_NUMBER"] as? Int, 
            let user = json["CREATED_BY"] as? String else { return nil }

    self.widgetNumber = widgetNumber
    self.user = user

    }
```

Comment: @Jacobi feel free to upvote to help out my reputation!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array of widget numbers you could use the `reduce` function which iterates the dictionaries in the array and extracts the widget numbers:

Using your data I put this in a storyboard:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [[String: Any]]

let widgetNumbers = json?.reduce(into: [String]()){ (accum, dict) in
    guard let widget = dict["WIDGET_NUMBER"] as? String else { return }
    accum.append(widget)
}

widgetNumbers // -> ["K11", "89704"]
```